# How to create angular @Input/@Output wrapper

Tags: angular, angular-decorator, angular-compiler

I have been experimenting with Angular 16, particularly with zoneless and signals, and I've accomplished some interesting stuff.

When working with component communication using @Input(), I found myself writing repetitive and cumbersome code like this:

```js
@Input('foo') set fooSetter(value: number) {
    this.foo.set(value);
}
foo = signal(0);
```

The issue I encountered is not specific to Angular 16 or signals, but rather with the @Input() decorator itself. I want to create a reusable code wrapper for this functionality.

The desired outcome is something like this:

```js
import { InputSignal } from './input-signal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
    standalone: true,
    // ...
})
export class FooComponent {
  @InputSignal() foo = signal(0);
}
```

This would call **'.set()'** on the signal instead of overriding it, also, the angular lsp and compiler should recognize this input as a number instead of a signal.

My first try was to create a custom decorator that uses the @Input decorator to extend its functionality.

```js
// input-signal.ts
import { Input } from "@angular/core"

export function InputSignal(...args: Parameters<typeof Input>): PropertyDecorator {
  return (target, key) => {
    const inputDecorate = Input(...args) as PropertyDecorator;
    const nativeInputKey = '__' + (getAlias(args) ?? String(key));
    inputDecorate(target, nativeInputKey);
    // More code...
  }
}

function getAlias([alias]: Parameters<typeof Input>): string | undefined {
  if (!alias) return undefined;
  if (typeof alias === 'string') return alias;

  return alias.alias;
}
```

Then, I checked it worked with the angular lsp and compiler, but, surprise, this error appeared:

> NG8002: Can't bind to 'foo' since it isn't a known property of 'app-foo'.

My next try was to check if the custom decorators support by angular even exits.

```js
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Input, signal, computed } from '@angular/core';
import { Input2 } from './input2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
    standalone: true,
    // ...
})
export class FooComponent {
  @Input2() foo = 2;
  // ...
}
```

Sadly, it did not work as well.

> NG8002: Can't bind to 'foo' since it isn't a known property of 'app-foo'.

Questions:

- Is there a way to interact with the Angular compiler to resolve this issue and make the custom decorator function as intended?

Comment: I just stepped over your question. I also have no good solution so far. Are you aware of this discussion about signal-based components? https://github.com/angular/angular/discussions/49682

Comment: @PeterT. yes, I saw they are going to add signal based inputs/outputs, it solves the problem I had, but I would be useful to be able to extend the @Input/@Output behavior (for interacting with observables for example).

I don't think they are going to add anything nearly related, surely it would introduce a lot of new bugs jaja.

Thanks.